# Creating an inset dark drop shadow effect with CSS

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

I'm trying to get an effect like an inset drop shadow effect in CSS that looks like the following image:

[image: image of sunken button]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/5c3178208bb904b3502a83a7490f7ffc.png))</sub>

Does any body know how I can get that effect with CSS?

Comment: Have you tried googling for "drop shadow effect css"?  There are tons of sites explaining how to do it.

Comment: It depends. What browser are you using?  If you're just stuck with CSS 2 or CSS3, you'll have difficulty, that is -- if you're using any version of IE before 9...

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/04/make-cool-and-clever-text-effects-with-css-text-shadow/) that explains it.

Comment: This only explains text-shadow, not how to make a button that looks like OP's image. It would have helped to at least include *some* reference to what you're linking to, at least name the CSS property used.

Comment: Well The Inset effect can be achieved by drawing a left and top light color in the border an a dark one in the right and bottom.

Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230383/inset-text-effect-with-css-text-shadow) gives you a hint.

Comment: Yeah i've done a fair amount of googling the only thing i can seem to find is test shadow effect. Unfortunately, those don't really get me anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has already been given to you (`box-shadow: inset ..`), so here's a quick demonstration of how it could work:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6nJj/

The important part is `box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px 0 red`.

For an explanation of the available options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/box-shadow#Values

Be sure to take into account the browser support for `box-shadow`, which is that it doesn't work in older versions of IE, but works "everywhere" else: http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

Answer (score 5):

The key here is **multiple** box shadows, a larger darker one inset from the top left and a very subtle shadow below thats slightly brighter than the background.

Notice the form of box-shadow is "x-offset, y-offset, blur, color"

Learn to use the blur amounts and multiple shadows and you can make some really nice effects.

Example style (for display on a background of #222):

```
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 3px 5px #000000, 0px 1px 1px #333;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the CSS3 `box-shadow` property, in particular, inset box shadows. Example L in [this article](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) should provide the effect you're looking for.